# Customize Filters in a view based on URL in Drupal 7

Tags: views

I have a view with contextual filter with a URL of `/taxonomy/term/%`.

So when I visit a URL on my site as `www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term`, it shows all the nodes which have the selected term.

Now the situation is that I have around 5 filters with this view, what I want is that if I go to a specific term page, I want hide filter based on a term name.

As an example, if I visit URL `www.mysite.com/taxonomy/term_1`, I want to hide one filter (let's say **filter_2**) out of five filters.

Is there any way I can do that?

I'll be grateful for your help.

Best.

Comment: Yes, definitely you can do that what you have to do is to an exposed form tpl and then in that you can print your widgets like :<?php print $widgets['filter-field_model_tid']->widget ; ?>

to know "filter-field_model_tid" use print_r($widgets);exit; on views exposed form tpl. Now here the trick in your first div get arguments from url and based on that you can show lets say if argument on a certain page is "term_1" you can show only 4 widgets in that div. now if argument is term_2 use another div and display widgets in that using if else conditions on arguments..

Comment: can I Post that in answer queue so that i can be awarded for the same?